# A Good Classic ASP Crutch: ASP.Net, Visual Basic, or something else

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp-classic

There is alot of bulk data processing, like moving large amounts of data, processing it and saving it into a database.. Gigs and Gigs.. If there is a website in classic ASP, what do you think would be the best 'on the side' application/solution to process large amounts of data in bulk. ASP.NET, Visual Basic? I know classic asp isn't the best option for importing in large amounts of data..  The data would need to interact with an SQL Server.

Comment: Pretty much any language/platform can be used to process data, given no more details than just that.

Comment: right, but gigs and gigs of data at once in bulk would be a little different, what would be most suitable for performance and speed?

Comment: If your only choices are classic ASP vs. ASP.NET then I'd recommend the latter just because it has more modern tooling available and is more widely used/supported.  But honestly, the language/platform used makes little difference compared to the design of the software itself.  There are still some very good applications written in classic ASP, and some very bad ones written in .NET.  Besides, you've given no specifics about the problem at hand.  As I said, any language/platform can load and process data, interact with a database, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to move lots of data I suggest you go right to the source and use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)(SQL Server Integration Services).

Comment: Can it handle T-SQL commands on the fly.. or is it more like the import/export tool?  These are batches of XML query responses being normalized into a database, relational.

Comment: Sky is the limit, read up on it, it's a nice skill to have.  Some people make a living with it alone.